# Refresh multiple div-[unique_ID]'s with jQuery and .load()?

Tags: jquery, ajax, load

I am working on modifying a plugin to allow users to vote on posts. My page looks something like this (though this is simplified of course):

```
<div class="vote vote1">
//voting buttons
</div>

<div class="vote vote2">
//voting buttons
</div>

<div class="vote vote3">
//voting buttons
</div>

<div class="vote vote4">
//voting buttons
</div>
```

As you can see, each voting div has a unique class associated with it, vote[id]. My trouble is that after submitting the vote to my vote.php file I need to refresh this unique voting div with the new data. I have been able to do this without trouble when I hardcode a particular voting div's unique id into .load(), but I cannot seem to get this to work dynamically for **all voting divs** using a single script. Would somebody be able to help me out in refreshing the unique voting div that has been clicked?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
$(".vote a.can-vote").click(
    function() {
        var some = jQuery(this).parent();
        var thepost = jQuery(this).attr("post");
        var theuser = jQuery(this).attr("user");
        var updown = jQuery(this).attr("up-down");
        var is_update = jQuery(this).attr("update");
        var votebox = ".vote"+thepost+" span";

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/vote.php",
            data: {user: theuser, post: thepost, up_down: updown, update: is_update},
            cache: false,
            success: function( data ){
                jQuery(some).load('http://mydomain.com div.vote[ID]');
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
}); 
</script>
```

I'm sorry if this is a simple question but I've been trying my best to figure it out for two days with no luck; thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Why not return the updated voting button from vote.php and save yourself a round trip?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?  There's nothing really obviously wrong with the script, as far as I can tell, though that URL in the ".load()" call looks a little weird.  Is that the issue? (Oh ... I think I see the deal now.)

Comment: @Tobias Cohen it's possible but because my voting button relies on so many built-in Wordpress function (which aren't loaded with the ajax call) I'd have to stuff vote.php with quite a bit of includes() and make it pretty bloated. Certainly an option though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood well:
 you can do an 'offline' trick. 
Just increment the vote number with jQuery, something like in this Ex:

```
var voted = 0;
$('.vote').attr('value', function() {
voted++;
return voted;
});
```

The change will happen in the browser.
Than always on page refresh you'll get back the real state from the DB.

Comment: But the `<div>` elements with the "vote" class don't *have* a "value" attribute ...

Comment: Right, that is just an idea, not a copy-paste. I thought maybe the buttons inside the DIVs ...

Comment: Thanks for the tip but I've got to return the true vote in case someone were to change their vote later (it goes up and down).

Answer (score 0):

Hmm ... well you could find the "ID" class via a regex:

```
$(".vote a.can-vote").click(
    function() {
        var some = jQuery(this).parent();
        var keyClass = some.attr('className').replace(/^.*(vote\d+).*$/, '$1');
```

Then your ".load()" can do:

```
          jQuery(some).load('http://mydomain.com div.' + keyClass);
```

You might also consider giving the `<div>` elements an actual "id" value too. That'd make stuff a little easier.

Comment: If I were to give the div's a unique id, say id="vote-[id]", would that make it easier? If so, how? Thank you by the way.

Comment: It would make it easier because you'd be able to just grab the "id" attribute from the parent `<div>`, instead of having to extract it from the "class" string. You could of course put the "id" in the class too, if that makes your CSS simpler.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you're using the "jQuery()"-selector instead of the $()-selector in order to avoid conflicts with other Javascript libraries on the page. Yet you are using the $-selector before ('.vote a.can-vote') and not the jQuery()-alternative. This might be the cause of your script not executing well.

You are able to use the regular $-selector by using the noConflict() function. (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

Comment: This is definitely, absolutely, unequivocally not the problem. It's also inherently contradictory; the "noConflict()" function restores the "$" symbol to whatever it was *before* jQuery claimed it.

Comment: Use `$` everywhere, it's easier to read. If this ever becomes an issue later (it probably won't), you can just wrap your code in `(function($){ ... })(jQuery);`.